# Return link pages instead of displaying them

Tags: functions

Is there any WP function to return the pages links instead of displaying them with `wp_link_pages()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $defaults = array(
        'before'           => '<p>' . __( 'Pages:' ),
        'after'            => '</p>',
        'link_before'      => '',
        'link_after'       => '',
        'next_or_number'   => 'number',
        'separator'        => ' ',
        'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page' ),
        'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
        'pagelink'         => '%',
        'echo'             => 0
    );
 ?>
```

You have to set the `echo` parameter to `0`. [Check the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages#Return_Values)